# Django alter current URL name and arguments

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

In my Django URLs, I have many URL patterns that end with :

```
 (redirect/(?P<redirect_to>\w+))
```

Which means that these URLs can be (or not) ending by `/redirect/TARGET/`. These URL patterns have other named arguments (mostly one : `pk`)

Now, I'd like, in the templates used by these URL patterns, to be able to alter the current page path, by just adding the redirect_to argument, and keeping the other arguments and URL reverse name untouched.

I was able to get the URL reverse name in the template, by adding `resolve(path).url_name` to the current context, and then to use that with the `{% url %}` template tag.

I'd like to know if there is any easy way to dynamically add the arguments (from `resolve(path).kwargs`) to the URL reverse tag ?

Comment: Not sure if you want this `{% url url_name my_kwarg1='any_value' my_kwarg2=context_var %}` Your question is confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you intending to add redirect logic to the actual template?

Comment: My original goal was to have three different forms, each redirecting at different places when the form was submitted. So I needed to have a way to get the altered URL in the page ending with /redirect/FOO. The template tag given in answer does the job, however I ended up doing what I had to do using a combination of submit button names (the name attribute of the submit button is passed as an empty key to the server when the form is submitted) and overriding get_success_url() in the base FormView.

Comment: @AamirAdnan that would work if I knew exactly the list of kwargs at each invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) for this (replacing your {% url %} tag with {% url_redirect "your_new_destination" %}).

in your_app/templatetags/my_custom_tags.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_redirect(context, new_destination):
    match = resolve(context.request.path)
    match.kwargs['redirect_to'] = new_destination
    return reverse(match.url_name, args=match.args, kwargs=match.kwargs)
```

in your template:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
{% url_redirect "your_new_destination" %}
```

Please note that you need to add 'django.core.context_processors.request' to your [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) in order for this snippet to work.